# ASP.NET MVC: Accessing ViewModel Attributes on the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, editorfor

Is there any way to access any attributes (be it data annotation attributes, validation attributes or custom attributes) on ViewModel properties from the view? One of the things I would like to add a little required indicator next to fields whose property has a [Required] attribute.

For example if my ViewModel looked like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int MyRequiredField { get; set; } 
}
```

I would want to do something in the EditorFor template like so:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<int?>" %>

<div class="label-container">
    <%: Html.Label("") %>

    <% if (PROPERTY_HAS_REQUIRED_ATTRIBUTE) { %>
        <span class="required">*</span>
    <% } %>
</div>
<div class="field-container">
    <%: Html.TextBox("") %>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessage("") %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The information you're looking for is in `ViewData.ModelMetadata`. Brad Wilson's [blog post series on Templates](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html) should explain it all, especially the post on [ModelMetadata](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html).

As far as the other ValidationAttributes go, you can access them via the [`ModelMetadata.GetValidators()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.getvalidators.aspx) method.

`ModelMetadata.IsRequired` will tell you if a complex type (or value type wrapped in `Nullable<T>`) is required by a `RequiredAttribute`, but it will give you false positives for value types that are not nullable (because they are implicitly required). You can work around this with the following:

```
bool isReallyRequired = metadata.IsRequired 
    && (!metadata.ModelType.IsValueType || metadata.IsNullableValueType);
```

Note: You need to use `!metadata.ModelType.IsValueType` instead of  `model.IsComplexType`, because `ModelMetadata.IsComplexType` returns false for MVC does not consider to be a complex type, which includes strings.

Comment: What about validation attributes like my EditorFor needs above? In that blog post Brad says the the only attributes that affect ModelMetadata are [HiddenInput], [UIHint], [DataType], [ReadOnly], [DisplayFormat], [ScaffoldColumn] and [DisplayName]

Comment: They're accessible via the GetValidators method. I've updated my answer to reflect this. I'm not sure about other non-validation attributes though.

Comment: The other way to get attribute information is via reflection. e.g. `typeof(YourModel).GetProperty("PropertyName").GetCustomAttributes()`, but you definitely shouldn't be doing that in a view.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not doing that way because you're adding logic in the view which is a bad practice.
Why don't you create a HtmlHelper or LabelExtension, you can call ModelMetaProvider inside the method and find out whether the property has Required attribute decorated?

Comment: Good point, though my example above was simplified. My question is more around how I find out whether the property has the required attribute. I had seen the ModelMetaProvider but its IsRequired property isn't dependent on the [Required] attribute. All I want is a list of attributes...