# Asp.Net MVC5 - Editorfor template, how to set field as not required?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to use an editor template for a complex property, but the fields in the template is by default set to require the user to fill them in. Is there an easy way to avoid this and still use 'editorfor'? I know there is a [required] data annotation, but i'm not using it and i can't find the opposite command. The template displays correctly, i just don't want the fields to be required.

Property in my view model:

```
[UIHint("EditPriceInfo")]
[Display(Name="Price info")]
public PriceInfo PriceInfo { get; set; }
```

From the template file '/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/EditPriceInfo.cshtml'. (Created by scaffolding from the class 'PriceInfo', see below.):

```
@model MyProject.Models.PriceInfo

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HourPrice, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HourPrice)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HourPrice)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DayPrice, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DayPrice)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DayPrice)
    </div>
</div>
```

Call to the template from the 'Edit'-view:

```
<h4>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PriceInfo)</h4>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PriceInfo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PriceInfo)
    </div>
</div>
```

And the properties in the original 'PriceInfo' entity:

```
[Display(Name = "Price/hour")]
public decimal HourPrice { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Price/day")]
public decimal DayPrice { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the accepted answer for [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7508037/2146734):

> ModelMetadata.IsRequired will tell you if a complex type (or value type wrapped in Nullable) is required by a RequiredAttribute, but it will give you false positives for value types that are not nullable (because they are implicitly required).

This means that the property in my example would be 'implicitly required' since it's a complex type that's not wrapped in Nullable<T>. I solved the issue by setting the properties in the 'PriceInfo' entity class to be nullable, like this (question marks after the type):

```
[Display(Name = "Price/hour")]
public decimal? HourPrice { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "Price/day")]
public decimal? DayPrice { get; set; }
```